# Use GROUP_CONCAT result in IN Clause Mysql

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I have a Query which returns comma separated integers
like :

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(ids) from table2
```

now I want to use that result in another query
like :

```
select * from table1 where column in (select GROUP_CONCAT(ids) from table2)
```

in this case it will consider only first value in IN clause.

Answer (score 9):

I agree with @Alma that this can't be done with IN, you might be able to do it with [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set), but if you can do it with IN it's probably a better approach :

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE find_in_set(ids, (
      SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ids)
      FROM table2
      )) != 0;
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/052cb/2)</kbd>

Comment: its not a good solution when you can directly use `IN()` , `GROUP_CONCAT` is not advisable because it has a character limit you need to increase that one if you used in your answer you need to brief also,when it can be done in simple way then why make set first then apply `find_in_set` it makes sense ?

Comment: i'm not saying it is a good approach. i'm advising to use IN instead, but i think this is what he was asking for.

Comment: is there any other way, to use in in where clause for the group_concat() values other then find_in_set

Answer (score 2):

Any special reason not using a join and using a sub query

```
select * from table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 on (t2.column = t1.ids)
```

Comment: why should this be done?